# Connection refused when using handlebars node template to set img src

Tags: node.js, image, templates, handlebars.js, src

I am new to using the templating functions in Node.  I am using the handlebars templating engine to render dynamic views on a node server.  I can render dynamic html, but am not able to set the src attribute for an image with a dynamic source.  I get a connection refused error from the browser:

```
GET uploads/CI_plot-II.png:1 GET http://localhost:8080/uploads/CI_plot-II.png net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am serving this image out of a static folder on the server, and when I GET it by navigating to it in the browser, I can see it, so I know it is there and live.

Relevant server code looks like this:

```
var hbs = require('hbs');
...
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
...
app.use(express.static('public'));
...
app.get("/manageResources", function(req, res, next){
  //get data about a yet-to-be approve resource and send it over to the client via the view
  db = createConnection()
  sql = "SQL QUERY ..."
  db.any(sql)
    .then(function(data){
      //parse the response
      nestedData = parseObjectDBResponse(data)
      localvars = {username: req.session.username, sessionID: req.session.id, resourceData: nestedData[0]}
      console.log(localvars)
      res.render('manageResources', localvars)
    }).catch(function(err){
      res.render("error", {error: err})
    })
})
```

And the client template looks like this:

```
  <body>
    <div class='col-xs-12'>
      <h5>References</h5>
      {{#each resourceData.references}}
        <li style="list-style: none" class='hangingindent'>{{this.string}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  <div id='image-holder' class='col-xs-6'>
    <img id='theImage' src={{resourceData.fileReference}}>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to do some workarounds like setting a `data` attribute on the image and then setting the src after the page loads with jQuery, but that doesn't work either.

I'm not really sure what's going on, or even whether the problem is on the client or server side.

Update:

If I refresh the page 3 or 4 times, sometimes the image shows up correctly.

Comment: What URL are you using when viewing the image in the browser? Perhaps your dynamic image path need a `public/` prefix?

Comment: I can see the image in the browser at the same URL that the html can't render. Adding the public prefix to the image doesn't seem to fix it, but it gives me a 404 (Not Found) instead of the connection refused error that I get without it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the problem was that I was using `nodemon` to automatically restart the server when a file changed.  Because I was using a `FileStore` session store, files would change every time a user navigated to a page in the website, so the server would automatically restart and cause the connection refused error.

Using regular node fixes the problem.